# Step in the proof that the product of two compact spaces is compact

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are compact topological spaces. In these lecture notes https://courses.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/view_material/5046, in section 2.2 it is proven that the product of $X$ and $Y$ is compact. We have the following step in the proof which I'm not quite sure whether it's valid:

> Let $\{W_i\}_{i \in I}$ be an open cover for $X \times Y$. 
>   Since the rectangular open sets $U \times V$ compose a basis for the product topology, we may write $X \times Y = \bigcup_{i\in I}W_i = \bigcup_{j \in J} U_j \times V_j$, where each $U_j\times V_j$ is contained in some $W_i$. **Therefore it is enough if we prove that the open cover $\{U_j\times V_j, j \in J\}$ has a finite subcover.**

Why is that true? So say given a finite subcover $\{U_j \times V_j\, j\in K\} \subseteq \{U_j \times V_j\, j\in J\}$, how do we construct a finite subcover of $\{W_i, i \in I\}$? I can see that if every basis element is only contained in finitely many $W_i$, then we can just pick those $W_i$ which contain the elements in $\{U_j \times V_j, j \in K\}$, but if a $U_j \times V_j$ is contained in infinitely many $W_i$, which $W_i$ do we select?

Comment: So every $W_i$ contains $U_i\times V_i$, take $i_1,...,i_n$ so that $\{U_{i_k}\times V_{i_k}\}$ is an open cover then so is $W_{i_k}$. Even if one rectengale is contained in infinitly many $W_i$ It is enough to take one of the $W_i$.

Comment: Not related to your question, but I'd rather be more surprised by the previous line where it cliams that $X=\bigcup W_i = \bigcup U_j\times V_j$; surely you could do this because $W_i$ cover $X$, but it seems to me that this assumes axiom of choice.

Comment: Just as an aside: Sounds like your question can be phrased in terms of open covers and a basis for topology, without reference specifically to cartesian products.

Answer (score 3):

Just pick *one* $W_i$ which contains each $U_j\times V_j$ (for each $j\in K$).  The union of such $W_i$ will then contain $U_j\times V_j$ for all $j\in K$ and hence they cover all of $X\times Y$.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of bookkeeping and using the axiom of choice at the start:

We write every $W_i$ as the union of basic rectangles, by the definition of a base :

$$W_i = \bigcup \{U_j \times V_j: j \in J(i) \}$$ for some index set $J(i)$.

Then clearly $$X \times Y  =\bigcup_{i \in I} W_i = \bigcup_{j \in \cup_{i \in I} J(i)} U_j \times V_j$$ so we use $J: = \cup_{i \in I} J(i)$ as the index set for the rectangles, and if the latter has a finite subcover using $U_{j_1} \times V_{j_1},\ldots U_{j_n} \times V_{j_n}$, then every $U_{j_k} \times V_{j_k} \subset W_{i_k}$ where $i_k$ is such that $j_k \in J(i_k)$ (recall that $J = \cup_{i\in I} J(i)$), and these $W_{i_k}, k=1\ldots n$ then cover $X \times Y$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if any set $X$ can be expressed as a union,

$X = \bigcup_{i \in I} W_i$

and you can also express each $W_i$ as a union

$W_i = \bigcup_{j \in J} V_j$

Then of course you can express $X$ as the union of $V_j$.

Now suppose you can find a collection of $V_k$ covering $X$.

Now each $V_k$ is contained in some $W_i$ for some $i$, so of course you can also express $X$ as a union of $W_{\bar{i}(k)}$ where the function $\bar{i}$ selects any index $i$ for any index $k$ satisfying $V_k \subseteq W_i$.

And if $k$ ranges over a finite index then of course you have a corresponding finite cover with the $W_{\bar{i}(k)}$.